# Android onConfigChange Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have a a code like this :

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private MaterialSearchView searchView;
private ImageView drawer,back;
private SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingLayout;
private ImageView btnHome,btnProfile,btnPromo,btnLogout;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initToolbar();
    init();
    searchView();
    setHome();
    setDrawer();
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setHome();
        }
    });
    btnProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setProfile();
        }
    });
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialogLogout();
        }
    });
}

public void init() {
    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    drawer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back);
    slidingLayout =(SlidingUpPanelLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    slidingLayout.addPanelSlideListener(onSlideListener());
    slidingLayout.setParallaxOffset(80);
    btnHome = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
    btnProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
    btnPromo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
    btnLogout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
}

public void drawerVisible(){
    drawer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void searchView(){
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void drawerChangeToBack(){
    drawer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}

public void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}

public void setDrawer(){
    drawer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFilter();
        }
    });
}

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    ft.commit();
}

private void setHome() {
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    setFragment(fragment);
}

private void setProfile() {
    Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    setFragment(fragment);
}
private void setAdvancedSearch() {
    Fragment fragment = new AdvancedSearchFragment();
    setFragment(fragment);
}

private void setFilter(){
    Fragment fragment = new FilterFragment();
    setFragment(fragment);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MaterialSearchView.REQUEST_VOICE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
            String searchWrd = matches.get(0);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchWrd)) {
                searchView.setQuery(searchWrd, false);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public static void setSelected(int selected) { }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setIcon(resizeImage(R.drawable.search_ic,200,200));
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5874e8"));
    searchView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    searchView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    MenuItem itemAdvanced = menu.findItem(R.id.action_advanced_search).setIcon(resizeImage(R.drawable.blue_dot,50,200));
    itemAdvanced.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            setAdvancedSearch();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void openDialogLogout() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure to logout?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   setHome();
}

private Drawable resizeImage(int resId, int w, int h)
{
    // load the origial Bitmap
    Bitmap BitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
    int width = BitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = BitmapOrg.getHeight();
    int newWidth = w;
    int newHeight = h;
    // calculate the scale
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapOrg, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
    return new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
}

private SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener onSlideListener() {
    return new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View view, float v) { }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) { }
    };
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setHome();
    if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return;

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If i rotate my device my all `Fragment` and btn function all gone i don't know why this happen . i want to ask how to handle rotation in device if i have a fragment . Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

For Landscape mode You have to create multiple layout which also used to support multiple screen.

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Because button may in end of the screen so if you rotate the it may gone missing but if you use different layout screen i may visible to you